# how to get count for queryresponse.getFacetField('xxx') in solr

Tags: solr

i am getting result as chennai(30), piler(40). i only need documents1 count present in the result. how can i do it in solr??? like in java if we have a arraylist with 20 elements we can get the size by list.size() rite likewise.

```
SolrQuery solrQuery1 = new SolrQuery(query1);
        solrQuery1.setFacet(true);
        solrQuery1.addFacetField('city');
        solrQuery1.setFacetMinCount(100);
        solrQuery1.setFacetLimit(9);
        solrQuery1.setQueryType("geo")
        solrQuery1.setParam("lat", city.latitude.toString())
        solrQuery1.setParam("long", city.longitude.toString())
        Double distanceInMiles = 300.0 * 0.621371192;
        solrQuery1.setParam("radius", distanceInMiles.toString());
        def server1 = solrService.getServer('provider')
        def queryResponse1 = server1.query(solrQuery1);
        def documents1 = queryResponse1.getFacetField('city');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on which version of SolrJ you're using, you can use either [`.getValueCount()`](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_9_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/response/FacetField.html#getValueCount()) (in recent versions) or count the elements in the list returned by [`.getValues()`](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_9_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/response/FacetField.html#getValues()) (by invoking `.size()`) for older versions.

To get the individual counts, [`getValues()`](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_9_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/response/FacetField.html#getValues()) on a [FacetField](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_9_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/response/FacetField.html) returns a list of [`FacetField.Count`](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_9_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/response/FacetField.Count.html) objects. These have two methods to retrieve the value and the count, `getName` and `getCount`. They return the name of the entry, and the count for that entry respectively.

Comment: i may not be clear in my question i want the count present in the bracket chennai(30), piler(40). like 30, 40. i use java to get value after opening bracket and closing bracket. but i was wondering how to do it using solr

Comment: @kiranreddy I've extended the answer.